# loop.nextitem doesn't work with current value from data

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to compare `postback.campaign_id` with the value of the next item. If it's similar, then, I don't print nothing, if not, then, print my row.

But, this code outputs everything.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="expand expand-campaign"><a>Test</a></td>
        <td>{{ account_id }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for postback in postbacks %}
        {% if loop.nextitem is defined and postback.campaign_id != loop.nextitem[0] %}
        <tr>
            <td></td><td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class="expand expand-site"><a>{{ postback.campaign_id }}</a></td>
        </tr>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loop.nextitem` contains the whole variable in your next item. So, if it is a dictionary or object, like in your case, you can access its properties like the current object under loop.

In your case that would mean:

```
postback.campaign_id != loop.nextitem.campaign_id
```

You also have the issue that your last item will always be skipped by the condition `loop.nextitem is defined`. Since you are going to always print the last item of a streak of similar items, you can perfectly do:

```
{% if loop.nextitem is undefined 
     or postback.campaign_id != loop.nextitem.campaign_id 
%}
```

Also note that, there is a `loop.changed()` construct in Jinja that can be handy in this specific use case.

---

So, with a list like:

```py
postbacks = [
  {'campagn_id': 1},
  {'campagn_id': 2},
  {'campagn_id': 2},
  {'campagn_id': 3},
  {'campagn_id': 3},
]
```

And this snippet of Jinja:

```
<table>
  {%- for postback in postbacks %}
    {%- if loop.changed(postback.campaign_id) %}
      <tr>
        <td class="expand expand-site">
          {{ postback.campaign_id }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
</table>
```

It renders, with some style added for clarity, as:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td class="expand expand-site">
          1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="expand expand-site">
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="expand expand-site">
          3
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```